# How can I configure a read aloud book for use in iBooks?

Tags: javascript, ios, epub, ibooks

I created an EPUB book for use in iBooks. To do so, I followed [this guide](http://www.albertopettarin.it/blog/2014/08/02/how-to-create-epub-3-read-aloud-ebooks.html). When I go to load the book I created into iBooks, it appears as a text-only ebook. The EPUB validator maintained by the IDPF (epubcheck) says that my book has no errors. What could I be doing wrong?

I have uploaded a copy of my book [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z2ce54gusqzvq1v/Hello%20World.epub?dl=1).

Comment: I would remove the javascript tag, as it is irrelevant for this question. I would add the `smil` or `media-overlay` tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your OPF has:

```
<meta property="media:active-class">-epub-media-oberlay-active-class</meta>
```

Clearly, a typo ("oBerlay" for "oVerlay"). Since your CSS has the MO active class rule named `-epub-media-overlay-active`, you should change it to:

```
<meta property="media:active-class">-epub-media-overlay-active</meta>
```

After the change, you will see your body highlighted when you start the MO rendition. (Tested in Readium, as I do not have my iPad at hand now.)

Comment: I forgot to add: `epubcheck` does not complain because it does not check that the CSS rule referenced by `<meta property="media:active-class">` actually exists...

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I tried your suggestion and fixed the incorrect reference. However, the book stubbornly will not let me start or stop the audio in iBooks. iBooks is the only accessible EPUB 3 reader I have handy and it is the one I am targeting. Any additional insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your OPF lacks the definition of the `rendition` prefix, and iBooks does not work without it. You can get a modified EPUB, which I tested it works in iBooks, from http://www.albertopettarin.it/misc/HelloWorld.epub | As you already know, at the end of my blog post you can download a working, complete EPUB.

Comment: Moreover, if you are targetting iBooks only, Apple has some proprietary extensions for dealing with embedded audio and/or Media Overlays, that you might find interesting. Read the "Apple iBooks Asset Guide" for details.